# jQuery current target in multiple selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, target

how can i retrieve which one of my selection is my "current" target?
I would like to have different variables inside this function.

```
$('#header a, #nav a').click(function (event) {

// if is $('#header a')  do this
// if is $('#nav a')  do that   

});
```

Comment: Either that or put the logic into one function and split the click into two calls calling the same function.

Comment: If you are doing two totally different things for the elements, you should attach an individual event handler to each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` will refer to the actual DOM element, and so you can check `tagName` or `className`, or look for `$(this).parents('#header')`.

```
$('#header a, #nav a').click(function (event) {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.parents("#header").length > 0) {
    display("I'm inside #header");
  }
  else if ($this.parents("#nav").length > 0) {
    display("I'm inside #nav");
  }
  else {
    // Obviously this won't happen.
    // None of us has *ever* changed a selector and forgotten to update the code! ;-)
    display("I'm confused!");
  }

  return false;

});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/afocu4)

---

**Off-topic**: I agree with Felix and melaos that if you're really doing things that different, refactoring into separate handlers (perhaps calling common functions) is probably the better way to go...

Answer (score 1):

**this** refers to the current element in the matches collection for the selector/s.
However if you need to process each element differently why do you want to bind the click event for the elements as a group (i.e using a single selector).

To manage the code in a better way I would use two bind calls like:

```
$("#header a").click(function (event) {
 //Do what you need to do for #header a
}); 

$("#nav a").click(function (event) {
 //Do what you need to do for #nav a
});
```